# 2nd TextView Not showing in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview

I have two TextViews here in my app but the second one doesn't show. How do I fix this?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Medieval 2" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:text="The Video Game"/>
```

Comment: What is the parent view? Possibly in a horizontal linear layout so that one textview takes up all the space?

Comment: Your linear layout must have property "orientation" to be default ( not set) , try to set "orientation = vertical", then you will see :)

Comment: but how do I make the first TextView in the middle of the screen and the other below?

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: @Vnge it shows it centered now at the top :( I need in the middle!

Comment: i think you are using a linear layout, find where it says `<LinearLayout xmls....`
change it to `<RelativeLayout xmls ....` Make sure you close the tags as `</RelativeLayout>`

in both textviews put `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

Replace

```
android:layout_below="@id/logo"
```

with

```
android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
```

If this doesn't work, the Graphical Layout might have a warning.

Comment: if you want make the first textview in the middle, you can use Margin Top

Comment: This is not really a solution. The '+' just generates a new resource ID in the R.java file.

Comment: @Love Grass how exactely do I do that? I'm using AIDE because it is a more comftorable environment for me then Eclipse ADT